# Powershell to get the output for each computer in specific format

Tags: output

Trying to get the HP Firmeware details using the HP cmdlets from mutliple Enclousre.

When the below command is execute the result is .

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> $new = $rus | Select-Object -ExpandProperty EnclosureComponentFirmwareInformation
C:\WINDOWS\system32> $new
```

Result:

```
Device     : TRAY
Name       : BladeSystem c7000 Onboard Administrator Tray
Location   :
Version    : 1.7
NewVersion : 1.7

Device     : LCD
Name       : BladeSystem c7000 Insight Display
Location   :
Version    : 2.2.2
NewVersion : 2.2.2

Device     : FAN
Name       : Active Cool 200 Fan
Location   : 1
Version    : 2.9.4
NewVersion : 2.9.4
```

When I try to take the result from multiple computer the result is:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> $new = $rus | Select-Object -Property IP,EnclosureComponentFirmwareInformation
C:\WINDOWS\system32> $new

IP                                                          EnclosureComponentFirmwareInformation
--                                                          -------------------------------------
1.1.1.1                                               {@{Device=TRAY; Name=BladeSystem c7000 Onboard Administr...
1.1.1.2                                             {@{Device=TRAY; Name=BladeSystem c7000 Onboard Administr...
```

I used Hash table format

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> $new = $rus | Select-Object -Property IP,@{Label="Device";Expression={[string]($_.EnclosureComponen
tFirmwareInformation.device)}},@{LAbel="Name";Expression={[string]($_.EnclosureComponentFirmwareInformation.Name)}},@{LA
bel="Location";Expression={[string]($_.EnclosureComponentFirmwareInformation.Location)}}
C:\WINDOWS\system32> $new

IP                            Device                        Name                          Location
--                            ------                        ----                          --------
1.1.1.1                TRAY LCD FAN FAN FAN FAN F... BladeSystem c7000 Onboard ...   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1.1.1.2               TRAY LCD FAN FAN FAN FAN F... BladeSystem c7000 Onboard ...   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

But i need result like the first output for each server.

```
IP

1.1.1.1

Device   Name               Location

Tray     BladeSystem          1

LCD      Bladesystem           2

FAN       Bladsystem..         3


1.1.1.2


Device   Name               Location

Tray     BladeSystem          1

LCD      Bladesystem           2

FAN       Bladsystem..         3
```

Pls let me know how can i modify my output..